# Slider for Plotly R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I have plotted two following graphs using ggplot2, using the following codes.

```
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = campaigns_profit_3months, aes(y = clients_3monthsBefore, x = c(1:41), group = 1, color = "Clients 3 Months Before"), 
            size = 1 ) +
  geom_line(data = campaigns_profit_3months, aes(y = clients_3monthsAfter, x = c(1:41), group = 1, color = "Clients 3 Months After"), 
            size = 1 )  + 
  xlab('Campaigns') + ylab('Clients') + ggtitle('Clients 3 months before and after the campaigns') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,41,1)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 200)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())

q <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = campaigns_profit_6months, aes(y = revenue_6monthsBefore, x = c(1:41), group = 1, color = "Revenue 6 Months Before"), 
            size = 1 ) +
  geom_line(data = campaigns_profit_6months, aes(y = revenue_6monthsAfter, x = c(1:41), group = 1, color = "Revenue 6 Months After"), 
            size = 1 )  + 
  xlab('Campaigns') + ylab('Revenue (USD)') + ggtitle('Revenue 6 months before and after the campaigns') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,41,1)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 200000)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())

plot(p)
plot(q)
```

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to add a slider bar or buttons(don't know if that's the right terminology) using Plotly to create two options 
`3 months revenue` and `6 months revenue`, where selecting the first option would display the first plot and selecting the second option would display the second?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `frame` aesthetic. Here is an example.

```
library(plotly)

dat <- iris
dat$months <- c(3,6)

gg <- 
  ggplot(dat, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species, frame = months)) + 
  geom_point()

ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

Comment: great answer! is there a way to manually drag the slider instead of pressing play?

Comment: (I posted a related question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66096701/r-plotly-dragging-sliders-instead-of-autoplay )