# R/plotly: Dragging Sliders Instead of Autoplay

Tags: r, animation, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. Using this previously asked question on stackoverflow ( [Slider for Plotly R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897286/slider-for-plotly-r)), I was able to make a "slider animation" (using the "plotly" library) for different values of  (a variable called) "var" within the data set:

```
#load libraries
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#generate data
var = rnorm(731, 100,25)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
data = data.frame(var,date)

#aggregate data
aggregate = data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
    summarise( Count = n())


#analysis for "99"

data$var_99 = 99
data$new_var_99 = ifelse(data$var >99,1,0)

#percent of observations greater than 99 (each month)
aggregate_99 = data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
    summarise( mean = mean(new_var_99))


#analysis for "98"

data$var_98 = 98
data$new_var_98 = ifelse(data$var >98,1,0)

#percent of observations greater than 98 (each month)
aggregate_98 = data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
    summarise( mean = mean(new_var_98))

#combine files together 

aggregate_98$var = 98
aggregate_98$var = as.factor(aggregate_98$var)

aggregate_99$var = 99
aggregate_99$var = as.factor(aggregate_99$var)

combine = rbind(aggregate_98, aggregate_99)

#make animation
gg <-ggplot(combine, aes(frame = var)) + geom_line(aes(x=month, y=mean, group=1))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) + ggtitle("Average Number of Observations Each Month Greater Than ....")

ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

However, it seems that it is not possible to "drag" the "circular slider button" (indicated by the red arrow). It seems I can only press the "play button" and the animation autoplays. Is there a way that this code can be modified so that you can "drag" the circular slider button across?

Thanks

EDIT: my session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.9.3  ggplot2_3.3.3 dplyr_1.0.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] pillar_1.4.7      compiler_4.0.3    tools_4.0.3       digest_0.6.27     jsonlite_1.7.2    lifecycle_0.2.0  
 [7] tibble_3.0.5      gtable_0.3.0      viridisLite_0.3.0 pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.10      cli_2.2.0        
[13] rstudioapi_0.13   withr_2.4.1       httr_1.4.2        generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.6       htmlwidgets_1.5.3
[19] grid_4.0.3        tidyselect_1.1.0  glue_1.4.2        data.table_1.13.6 R6_2.5.0          fansi_0.4.2      
[25] purrr_0.3.4       tidyr_1.1.2       magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1      ellipsis_0.3.1    htmltools_0.5.1.1
[31] assertthat_0.2.1  colorspace_2.0-0  utf8_1.1.4        lazyeval_0.2.2    munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have to change anything at all! Just click and drag. Your *exact* code works perfectly well on my end. And this isn't a new feature either since I'm on `Package plotly version 4.9.1` in RStudio.

#### Click

[image]

#### Drag

[image]

Comment: thank you! i will try again and let you know (I just added my session info)

Comment: @Noob You're welcome! But does it still not work for you?

Comment: ok, you were correct - everything works! I added segments for "97" and "96" and now its much easier to see the slider being dragged. thank you!

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109378/r-adding-multiple-sliders-to-the-same-graph-error-aesthetics-must-be-eithe