# Adding Multiple "sliders" to the same Graph

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization, interactive, r-plotly

I am using the R programming language. Using the "plotly" library, I was able to make the following interactive graph:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

library(dplyr)
#generate data
set.seed(123)

var = rnorm(731, 100,25)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
data = data.frame(var,date)

vals <- 90:100
combine <- vector('list', length(vals))
count <- 0
for (i in vals) {
    
    data$var_i = i
    data$new_var_i = ifelse(data$var >i,1,0)
    
    #percent of observations greater than i (each month)
    aggregate_i = data %>%
        mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
        group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
        summarise( mean = mean(new_var_i))
    
    #combine files together
    
    aggregate_i$var = i
    aggregate_i$var = as.factor(aggregate_i$var)
    
    count <- count + 1
    combine[[count]] <- aggregate_i
    
}

result_1 <- bind_rows(combine)
result_1$group = "group_a"
result_1$group = as.factor(result_1$group)

######

var = rnorm(731, 85,25)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
data = data.frame(var,date)

vals <- 90:100
combine <- vector('list', length(vals))
count <- 0
for (i in vals) {
    
    data$var_i = i
    data$new_var_i = ifelse(data$var >i,1,0)
    
    #percent of observations greater than i (each month)
    aggregate_i = data %>%
        mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
        group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
        summarise( mean = mean(new_var_i))
    
    #combine files together
    
    aggregate_i$var = i
    aggregate_i$var = as.factor(aggregate_i$var)
    
    count <- count + 1
    combine[[count]] <- aggregate_i
    
}

result_2 <- bind_rows(combine)
result_2$group = "group_b"
result_2$group = as.factor(result_2$group)

#combine all files

final = rbind(result_1, result_2)

gg <-ggplot(final, aes(frame = var, color = group)) + geom_line(aes(x=month, y=mean, group=1))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) + ggtitle("title")

gg = ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

Now, I am trying to make two separate "sliders" : one "slider" for "group_a" and another "slider" for "group_b". Something that looks like this:

[image]

My logic is, the "frame" argument within the "ggplot()" statement should have two levels:

```
gg <-ggplot(final, aes(frame = c(var,group), color = group)) + geom_line(aes(x=month, y=mean, group=1))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) + ggtitle("title")

gg
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (550): frame
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You should decide whether you want to use `<-` *or* `=` for assignment, and stick with that. Donʼt mix them.

Comment: Sorry, i will try to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with the standard `plotly` API.

I think for cases like this it is better to use `shiny` and create a web application. You can add as many sliders as you need and then filter the data as needed to update the plots.

The downside to this is that you are just redrawing the plots with new data, as opposed to doing animations like before. So you end up loosing the smooth transitions that you had before.

There is actually a way of keeping the animation aspect that I didn't know, but you need to go deeper into `shiny`/`plotly`. Take a look at [this link](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-animate-plotly-plot-in-shiny-when-data-changes-solved/33228). I didn't know about this, so I didn't try to do it. But i will take a look at it later!

Here is my solution with shiny:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

gendata <- function(){
    #generate data
    set.seed(123)
    
    var = rnorm(731, 100,25)
    date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
    data = data.frame(var,date)
    
    vals <- 90:100
    combine <- vector('list', length(vals))
    count <- 0
    for (i in vals) {
        
        data$var_i = i
        data$new_var_i = ifelse(data$var >i,1,0)
        
        #percent of observations greater than i (each month)
        aggregate_i = data %>%
            dplyr::mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
            dplyr::group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
            dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(new_var_i), .groups='drop')
        
        #combine files together
        
        aggregate_i$var = i
        aggregate_i$var = as.factor(aggregate_i$var)
        
        count <- count + 1
        combine[[count]] <- aggregate_i
        
    }
    
    result_1 <- bind_rows(combine)
    result_1$group = "group_a"
    result_1$group = as.factor(result_1$group)
    
    ######
    
    var = rnorm(731, 85,25)
    date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
    data = data.frame(var,date)
    
    vals <- 90:100
    combine <- vector('list', length(vals))
    count <- 0
    for (i in vals) {
        
        data$var_i = i
        data$new_var_i = ifelse(data$var >i,1,0)
        
        #percent of observations greater than i (each month)
        aggregate_i = data %>%
            dplyr::mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
            dplyr::group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
            dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(new_var_i), .groups='drop')
        
        #combine files together
        
        aggregate_i$var = i
        aggregate_i$var = as.factor(aggregate_i$var)
        
        count <- count + 1
        combine[[count]] <- aggregate_i
        
    }
    
    result_2 <- bind_rows(combine)
    result_2$group = "group_b"
    result_2$group = as.factor(result_2$group)
    
    # combine all files
    # note: sliderInput needs numeric data, so I converted values of "var" to numeric
    final <- rbind(result_1, result_2)
    final$var <- as.integer(as.character(final$var))

    return(final)
}

final <- gendata()

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column=12,
             plotlyOutput("lineplot")),
    fluidRow(column=12,
             # create slider for group a
             sliderInput("groupa", "Group A:",
                         min = min(final$var), max = max(final$var),
                         value = min(final$var), step = 1,
                         animate =
                             animationOptions(interval = 300, loop = FALSE),
                         width='95%')),
    fluidRow(column=12,
             # create slider for group b
             sliderInput("groupb", "Group B:",
                         min = min(final$var), max = max(final$var),
                         value = min(final$var), step = 1,
                         animate =
                             animationOptions(interval = 300, loop = FALSE),
                         width='95%')))

server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    # create a reactive dataframe with filtered data for group a at current value of var
    df.a <- reactive({
        final %>% dplyr::filter(group == 'group_a') %>%
            dplyr::filter(var == input$groupa)
    })
    
    # create a reactive dataframe with filtered data for group b at current value of var
    df.b <- reactive({
        final %>% dplyr::filter(group == 'group_b') %>%
            dplyr::filter(var == input$groupb)
    })
    
    # Create plotly with filtered data
    output$lineplot <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly() %>%
            add_trace(data=df.a(), x=~month, y=~mean, color=~group, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', colors = 'Set1') %>%
            add_trace(data=df.b(), x=~month, y=~mean, color=~group, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', colors = 'Set1')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! everything works perfectly! the only reason I wanted to do this in plotly because its much easier to save the final output as a html file. I am not sure if it is possible to save rshiny outputs as a html file?

Comment: Yes and no. "Yes" because when you use shiny you are actually creating an html file on the client side with the UI. "No" because this html file does not have all the data. It "talks" to a server which is the one who has the data and performs all the data manipulation and then sends it back to the client. If you want a self contained html, then you probably need your approach. Maybe it is possible with plotly. Let me see if I can do it and I will add to my answer.

Comment: I posted a similar question here what I tried to do this all in plotly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109378/adding-multiple-sliders-to-the-same-graph thank you for all your help