# What does the `ggplotly` function fail with the `frame` argument? "Error in -data$group : invalid argument to unary operator"

Tags: r, debugging, plotly, ggplotly

I want to make a stacked bar chart with a `slider` for the `Year` variable with the `plotly` package.

I use the `frame` argument but I get an error.

I try to reproduce the code from [this thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58920828/8806649)

```r
summary <- structure(list(Language = c("English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "German", "German", "German", "German", "German", "German", "German", "German", "German", "German", "German", "German", "German", "German"), category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "Langues et Litteratures", "Materiaux, Milieux et Chimie", "MathÃ©matiques", "Mathematiques et Informatique", "Medecine", "Psychologie", "Science de l'ingÃ©nieur", "Science de la Terre", "Sciences de l'education", "SHS"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003), n = c(20L, 39L, 41L, 53L, 1L, 3L, 12L, 8L, 22L, 2L, 11L, 17L, 18L, 44L, 29L, 38L, 46L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L))

library(ggplot2); library(plotly)

gg <- ggplot(summary) +
  aes(x = Language, y = n, fill = category, frame = Year) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")

print(gg)
```

[image]

```r
ggplotly(gg)
```

```r
Error in -data$group : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Comment: It works with `geom_point()`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `position = 'identity'` to make the animation like this:

```r
library(ggplot2); library(plotly)

gg <- ggplot(summary) +
  aes(x = Language, y = n, fill = category, frame = Year) +
  geom_col(position = 'identity')

ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't get the same chart with `ggplot(summary %>% filter(Year == 2000)) +
  aes(x = Language, y = n, fill = category, frame = Year) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")` for `Year == 2000`